# My TFS build definition setup cannot get past Get Sources error 'directory already exists'

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

My TFS 2018 build fails at GET SOURCES with this error:

- tf vc get /version:192 /recursive /overwrite
  C:\Users\Administrator\agent_work\2\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,
  /noprompt C:\Users\Administrator\agent_work\2: Warning s - Unable to
  get because a directory already exists. Exit code 1 returned from
  process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc get /version:192 /recursive
  /overwrite C:\Users\Administrator\agent_work\2\s /loginType:OAuth
  /login:., /noprompt'.

**My steps**
I have a fresh installation of TFS 2018.
I created an agent pool (default)
I created the agent
The VSTS service is running
I created a simple Visual Studio 2017 C# winforms project
I added the solution to TFS
I mapped the workspace

**In Get sources...**
I set CLEAN to true ... and it is set up for Clean Sources. My server path is directly to the solution file within the repository.

But the above error keeps happening.

Any ideas? Help!

Comment: Does the agent service account have full control over the agent_work folder?

Comment: Yes it does, Full control (modify, read & execute, etc.) I just checked.

Comment: @anthony_s If you login the build agent machine and delete folder `2` in ` C:\Users\Administrator\agent_work` manually, will the issue persist?

Comment: Yes, it'll recreate itself every time I run a build (after logging out, logging back in).  It recreates the _work folder.  And it will error with the same message.

Comment: What is your agent version? Is it 2.126.0? Could you try to re-configure your build agent to see whether it works?

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to "true" and then share the build logs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this problem and it turned out it was because I'd specified the solution file in the "server path" box rather than the source directory.

Initially I had the server path set to $/Modelling/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.sln and got the error above, then I changed it to $/Modelling/ConsoleApp1 and the problem went away.

Comment: I believe this is the real answer to the question. I had the same error and changing the server path in the "get sources" task to a directory and not the solution was an immediate fix to an obscure error that took a long time to find. Thanks...

Comment: i had this same issue and this was the fix - tysm!!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the Agent folder structure, deleted the agent as well. And in TFS deleted the build definition.  I opted to start from scratch, and after reconstructing the new AGENT and creating the new Repository with Build Definitions, it worked.  The error stopped.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer later, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Another fix is if your "Server Path" is a single file, then the "Local Path" should be that file's name with the extension instead of blank. $/MyPath/MySolution.sln -> MySolution.sln