# Error when building Azure DevOps: : Warning s - Unable to get because a directory already exists

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, azure-devops-server-2019

I am getting the below error when building a project via Azure DevOps pipeline. I have checked for pending changes or files not mapped, but don't see any. I am not sure what else to try here.

Snippet from log:

```
##[command]tf vc get /version:6 /recursive /overwrite C:\agents\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.153.1\_work\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
C:\agents\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.153.1\_work\1:
Warning s - Unable to get because a directory already exists.

Exit code 1 returned from the process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc get /version:6 /recursive /overwrite C:\agents\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.153.1\_work\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt'.
```

Images of my configuration:
[image]

EDIT: I tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406966/2016162), with no success.